# Extract data from API

Tags: javascript, fetch, react-native, response

Maybe the question might be too simple but I can't get the data

This is the response of API:

```
[{"city_id": 33, "city_name": "Nagpur", "country_id": 1, "country_name": "India", "entity_id": 33, "entity_type": "city", "latitude": 21.15, "longitude": 79.09, "title": "Nagpur"}]
```

this response is being stored inside "a", now when I set state,

```
this.setState({lat: a})
```

It shows the same data in the log but when I try to extract latitude and longitude it shows undefined.
I'm doing this to extract data

```
this.setState({lat : a.latitude})  // shows undefined
```

Please Help me !!!!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: No, I don't think so

Comment: Since it is an array, we can do get the value by index. Please refer @Ian Pilipski's comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a is array in your response so try:

```
this.setState({lat : a[0].latitude})
```